# Сервер Django не работает

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка? не могу сервер запустить.

python manage.py runserver (doesn't work)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Вы не установили через pip coursheders. Или удалите его из SETTINGS или установите через pip

Comment: File "C:\Users\Miras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Miras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение
  File "C:\Users\Miras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720

Comment: Какая проблема может быть здесь?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525915/python-socketserver-error-upon-connection похоже на ваш вопрос ответ находится тут